# Error "package does not exist" when I compile Java file that uses jar archive

Tags: java

I created jar archive using this in terminal `jar -cf bjamee.jar bjamee`. Then I moved this jar archive to the directory where my Java file exists.

```
import bjamee.GameObject;

public class MyGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    }

}
```

`GameObject.class` exists in jar archive. So to compile `MyGame.java` I used `javac -cp /bajamee.jar: MyGame.java`, but I got this error. Do you know what step I do something wrong on.

[image]

My Java file and jar archive are in the same directory.

[image]

That's an error when I use `javac -cp bjamee.jar: MyGame.java`.

[image]

Comment: what's the full name of the package, as displayed on your machine?

Comment: /home/vladislav/Documents/game/bjamee.jar is full name of file in my operation system.

Comment: but i don't think that is the package name, because you're telling java to use the package  bjamee.GameObject, and it doesn't seem like it exists

Comment: "Then I moved this jar archive to the directory where my Java file exists" - you don't need `/`, use `javac -cp bjamee.jar MyGame.java`.

Comment: When I don't use `/` I get another error.

Comment: Have you tried this?: javac -cp ./bajamee.jar: MyGame.java (dot will indicate to be relative to the current folder)

Comment: The GameObject class does not have the correct package declaration. Package structure must always match directory structure. Include "package bjamee;" at the top of GameObject, recompile and it should work. (Also, use a proper build tool that keeps track of this stuff for you!)

Comment: Thanks I have already solve this problem. The problem was that you said.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `javac -cp .:/bajamee.jar: MyGame.java`.

Hope it helps

**EDIT**
I have reproduce similar thing.

So I have `com.company.Main` which is import `bjamee.GameObject`

```
package com.company;
 import bjamee.GameObject;
 
 public class Main {
 
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("test");
     }
 }
```

Wrong compile because bjame/GameObject.class is not provided in current folder.

```
» javac -cp .:/bjamee.jar Main.java                                                                                              03:01:49
Main.java:2: error: package bjamee does not exist
import bjamee.GameObject;
             ^
1 error
```

```
» cp -r ../../bjamee .

» tree                                                                                                                           03:04:08
.
├── bjamee
│   ├── GameObject.class
│   └── GameObject.java
└── com
    └── company
        ├── bjamee
        │   ├── GameObject.class
        │   └── GameObject.java
        ├── bjamee.jar
        ├── Main.class
        └── Main.java

4 directories, 7 files

» ls
  bjamee/  bjamee.jar  Main.class  Main.java

» javac -cp .:/bjamee.jar Main.java
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help me. Does this happen because I am on Linux?

Comment: Errors are that're on the pictures in my question.

Comment: Please check my edited answer, you can find more detail in http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-classpath-work-in-java.html

Answer (score 0):

I’ve solved my problem. The problem was that when I created jar archive I put class files into folder. That means that my class files actually are in package. So I imported my class files using import bjamee.GameObject. But that was wrong because though in my jar archive in bjamee folder was classes they didn’t say that they’re in that folder (package). I added package bjamee to my Java files compiled them created jar archive. And now everything work fine. I know a little bit about packages because I am on 300 out of 700 pages in Head First, but I am sure I can get through it.

Thank Taschi though for helping me, you are only who understand where the problem was in.